# Getting PID for a process running on a remote node

Tags: erlang

I am new to Erlang and we are working on a small scale messaging server.

We are trying to build a process registry using Redis ( not planning to use existing once grpoc, global etc due to other business needs ) as a datastore ( store to hold user-id to "node | PID " mapping). When a process starts it register itself with Redis in the form user_id (key) and {node | pid } as value. ( pid is tored as string in redis)

example value inserted in redis are "user_abc", {one@mf, "0.37.0>"}

Now when I try to find PID for "user_abc" which is running in the cluster - i get {node and pid} as value on a remote node which in this case is {one@mf, "0.37.0>".

Question is how do we use {node, pid} details on remote node to connect to the process user_abc.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a "cluster wide" pid by parsing that pid on the remote node:

On node `a`:

```erlang
(a@host)1> pid_to_list(self()).
"<0.39.0>"
```

On node `b`:

```erlang
(b@host)1> Pid = rpc:call('a@host', erlang, list_to_pid, ["<0.39.0>"]).
<7101.99.0>
(b@host)2> Pid ! my_test.
my_test
```

On node `a`:

```
(a@host)2> flush().
Shell got my_test
ok
```

**Note that the process might not be alive**, so calling `erlang:monitor/2` on it before talking to it might be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks Adam. Is there any other method where you dont need to make a RPC call to convert this to Pid? I get the PID from Redis stored based on UserId and then followed the steps listed below.. this does convert but not sure if this is the most efficient and only method to get PID.                                         [Node, PidStr ] = re:split(UserKeyValue, ":"),
 PidStrList = binary_to_list(PidStr),
 {done,{ok,T,_},[]} = erl_scan:tokens([], PidStrList,1),
 {ok,Tree} = erl_parse:parse_exprs(T),
 {value,Res,[]} = erl_eval:exprs(Tree,[]),
 Pid =  binary_to_term(Res),
 [Node, Pid ].

Comment: Well, both that and using `list_to_pid/1` locally would give you a local PID (which doesn't exist). Then doing an RPC call would give you a pid pointing to the current node, and not the remote one. If you don't need the pid on the current node, why bother parsing it at all?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store erlang pid to redis, and want other node read it as a remote pid, use **`erlang:term_to_binary(Pid)`** to store, and use **`erlang:bianry_to_pid(PidBin)`** to read.

See this post:[Erlang Pid](https://wudixiaotie.github.io/erlang/2016/04/15/erlang-pid.html)