# How to get in erlang the pid of a node name?

Tags: erlang, pid

I got a node: **app01@mdiaz** and I need to know the pid (something like **<2908.77.0>** )

Comment: You question is confusing. You want the pid or the node?

Comment: For the question in your title, you can use erlang:node/1.
For the pid of a process in a node, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32708758/getting-pid-for-a-process-running-on-a-remote-node

Comment: I need to get the pid

Answer (score 7):

An Erlang node doesn't have one single pid: there are many processes running on each node, so you need to specify which one you want.

If you want to know the pid of the process registered with the name `foo` on the node `bar@localhost`, you can make an RPC call to [`erlang:whereis/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#whereis-1):

```
(foo@localhost)1> rpc:call(bar@localhost, erlang, whereis, [foo]).
<7120.56.0>
```

Though you might not need that: if you want to send a message to a named process on another node, you can use `{Name, Node}` instead of first getting the pid.  For example, to send a message to the process called `foo` on `bar@localhost`:

```
{foo, bar@localhost} ! my_message
```

---

You can also go the other direction, getting the node name from a pid, with the `node/1` function:

```
(foo@localhost)1> RemotePid = rpc:call(bar@localhost, erlang, whereis, [foo]).
<6928.32.0>
(foo@localhost)2> node(RemotePid).
bar@localhost
```